# VideoView Reproducir varios videos

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-intent

Hola amigos tengo pequeño problema que no se como realizar, bueno estoy tratando de reproducir unos vídeos en mp4 al cual necesito que cuando arranque el primero y e acabe arranque un segundo vídeo la verdad no se como hacerlo.

```
public class Videos extends AppCompatActivity {
    VideoView videoView;
    Button siguiente;
    int mas=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_videos);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        siguiente=(Button)findViewById(R.id.siguiente);

        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              if (mas==0)
              {
                  mas=1;
              }else
                if (mas==1)
                {
                    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.admin.relojfinal/" + R.raw.video1);
                    MediaController mc = new MediaController(Videos.this);
                    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
                    videoView.setVideoURI(path);
                    videoView.start();
                    mc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mas=2;
                }else
                    if (mas==2)
                    {
                        Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.admin.relojfinal/" + R.raw.video2);
                        MediaController mc = new MediaController(Videos.this);
                        videoView.setMediaController(mc);
                        videoView.setVideoURI(path);
                        videoView.start();
                        mc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar esto precisamente se tiene el listener **[OnCompletionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener))** para detectar cuando termina la reproducción de un archivo, en base a esto puedes reproducir el siguiente y así sucesivamente:

```
  videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            //Termina la reproducción, reproduce el siguiente video.      
            startNextVideo();

            }
        });
```

El método `startNextVideo()` podría definir el `Uri` del siguiente video de la lista e iniciar su reproducción.

---

Agrego un ejemplo de lo que comento, una respuesta realizada por [@BlueSword](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3098658/bluesword):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21550404/250260

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            startOtherVideo();
        }
});
```

Metodo que sería llamado al completar la reproducción del mp4.

```
private void startOtherVideo(){
  //Asegura detener reproducción.
  videoView.stopPlayback();
  //Define Uri del siguiente video.
  videoUri = Uri.parse("<PATH SIGUIENTE VIDEO>");
  videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
  //Inicia reproducción nuevamente.
  videoView.start(); 
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias el metodo me esta funcionando perfecto... a hora lo que trato hacer es que en un areglo meto 3 numeros aleatorios con estos 3 numeros me salga los videos de esos 3 numeros aleatorios estoy tratando de hacer eso.... muchas gracias

Comment: Que bien Brayan, trata de implementar lo que comentas y si hay dudas agrega otra pregunta, saludos!